# State where the resulting state is the argument provided and the value is unit

Tags: haskell, state-monad

Exercise `23.8.2` in the haskell book asks me to construct a state like the following:

```
put' :: s -> State s ()
put' s = undefined
-- should act like:
-- Prelude> runState (put "blah") "woot"
-- ((),"blah")
```

The only implementation I have gotten to typecheck is

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.State -- Not sure this is the right import
put' :: s -> State s ()
put' s = state $ \s -> ((), s)
```

But this returns the state in the argument of `runState`, not `put'`:

```
λ> runState (put' "blah") "woot"
((),"woot")
```

What haskell acrobatics do I need to fix this? Do not see how I can access the `"blah"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
put' s = state $ \s -> ((), s)
     ^            ^
```

You reused the variable `s` for two different bindings. Try using a different name, and the solution will be obvious ;-)

By the way, you should enable warnings using the `-Wall` flag in GHC / GHCi. This would have pointed out that you have defined `s` twise, and the second binding shadows the first one.

Comment: Yes, yes, lambda equivalence (or some such...)